# Eclipse is asking for a jarfile from a folder that I no longer have

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I did some school work on a school PC and I added a file to my eclipse library 
that existed in a folder path from the school PC.

When I got home all of my projects have folder path errors on them and when I 
tried to download that file again and add it to my eclipse library it doesn't 
count it and still asks for the that exact same file but from the school PC 
folder path.

I don't know what to do because I can't just remove it.

Adding it as an external file doesn't solve the problem because it still asks for that file from the school folder path.

e.g.:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

As you can see in the first image it doesn't let me remove the jar file or edit it.

In the second picture you can see how all of my projects have errors due to this missing file. You can also see how I tried to add it as an external jar and it didn't recognize it

Comment: Image links will get stale and make this question less useful over time. SO accepts inline images, so you should re-edit the question to include them. BTW, "Eclipse fixing library problems" yields lots of existing answers here and on the greater internet.

Comment: Check the build path. You should see one entry in libraries that is broken. Change the dependencies/libraries management to maven/gradle. This should make it all easier.

Comment: i tried searching for answers in the internet first but i didn't find anything suiting for me

Comment: @efekctive can you please explain how to do that , i am new to this software and i don't really understand these terms .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the .classpath file inside the imported project is not hidden. If it is hidden then unhide it and then try again to delete the jars you don't want.

Comment: hello, i don't really know how to do that i tried changing the source path or file or whatever and it told me that the .classpath file does not refer to an existing library and the .classpath file is nowhere to be found

Comment: ok at first make sure you change folder options to show hidden files, then go to the folder where it has the project, you should find now 2 files .classpath and .project, make both of them as unhidden.